# AWS Security Groups Use a /32 CIDR which I thought masked everything. How does it work?

Tags: networking, ip, amazon-web-services, subnet

In AWS security groups, an IP address exception is given as follows:

x.x.x.x/32

Isn't /32 a notation to signify 255.255.255.255?  Doesn't that mean that the entire IP address is masked?  How do I understand this x.x.x.x/32 notation in AWS Security Groups?  I would not think an underlying IP address could be relevant if the mask was 255.255.255.255.  I thought /32 was the same as 255.255.255.255.

Answer (score 2):

`/32` *is* equivalent to 255.255.255.255... but a subnet mask doesn't hide anything.  The subnet mask masks the bits in the network portion of the netblock -- the bits which cannot vary.

If none of the bits can vary, then necessarily you have defined a "block" of IP addresses of size = 1... the given address.

203.0.113.64/32 means exactly that single IP address, 203.0.113.64.

On an actual network, you wouldn't typically see a 255.255.255.255 subnet mask, but you aren't configuring a network, you're specifying a low/high range of IP addresses that match the filter rule.

Remember also that the subnet mask has no meaning outside the immediate local network context.  I might have a subnet here where the subnet is 203.0.113.128/25 (255.255.255.128) but I only need to access you from just one machine -- let's say 203.0.113.200.  Your correct mask for that address, to allow me to access your system would still be /32 -- my local subnet mask for the same address has no meaning to you.

Answer (score 1):

I thought /32 was the same as 255.255.255.255.

Yes, it is the same. Both are different notations for the same thing.

A /32 as a traditional network does not make sense. You would have one network IP, one broadcast IP and nothing for hosts on it. However when using point to point connections they do make sense. Or as a static route for a single IP.

The last seems to be what you are after.